# Is it correct to distinguish between "messenger" and "angel"?

Tags: greek, hebrew, translation-philosophy

Both Hebrew and Greek have each one word that is translated with either *messenger* or *angel*.

I am wondering if the distinguishing between messenger and angel in English (or between Bote and Engel in German for that matter) is an unnecessary one.

Would the Hebrews or Greeks 2000 and more years ago feel that the respective word is a homonym?